# Is it possible to control facebook chatbot externally?

Tags: python, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I want to develop a chatbot for a few Facebook pages(which will deploy in 5 pages). I want to control all the chatbot externally from the outside admin panel. Like I want to send a message from my admin panel to a page bot or I want to reply on a specific page. I want to see all the messages and want to respond.

Now my question, Is it possible to control one more Facebook page from a single platform?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle both, automated replies and "manual" live agent replies, you can utilize the Handover Protocol. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/, this allows forwarding a conversation to the regular Page Inbox or another 3rd party app.